# Laravel continue looping in transform method

Tags: php, laravel, loops, collections, continue

What is the equivalent of `continue` while looping in `transform()`?

I want to do something like this:

```
$collection->transform(function($item) {
    if ($condition) {
        continue;
    }
    return $item['key'];
});
```

One option will be to do a `->reject()` after `transform` is completed but is there a way to do it while still looping?

P.S: The goal is to actually return a new collection with one element less. E.g.

```
[
    '1',
    '2',
]

=> when $condition:

[
    '1',
]

$collection->transform(function($item) {
    if ($condition) {
        return ['']; // <- This didn't work!
    }
    return $item['key'];
});
```

Comment: `use ($condition)` you need to pass this inside closar

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the `collection->reduce()` method:

```
$collection->reduce(function($result, $item) {
    if (!some_condition_etc...) {
        $result->push($item['key']);
    }
    return $result;
}, collect());
```